# Which would be faster?

Tags: javascript, optimization

Which of these would be faster or would they basically take the exact same time.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fillRect(5 + i * 2, 5, 5, 5);
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect(5 + i * 2, 15, 5, 5);
}
```

vs

```
c.fillStyle = "black";
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    c.fillRect(5 + i * 2, 5, 5, 5);
}

c.fillStyle = "red";
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    c.fillRect(5 + i * 2, 15, 5, 5);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because WHY DONT YOU JUST TRY IT?

Comment: BTW they don’t do the same thing: version 1) sets fill style every iteration and interleaves the fills, and the opposite is true for version 2)

Comment: @charlieftl pure speculation. *If* this would be compiled down to perfect bytecode, they would go roughly over the same number of statements, therefore taking an equal time.

Comment: @charlietfl  I think the OP might be thinking there are more color switches with 1,.. So 2 loops might be faster, but it might be slower.. mmm..  Anyway welcome to profile my code, oops sorry wrong site..

Comment: @jonas perhaps the question is a theoretical nano-optimisation one, not easily measurable (although I doubt the answer would matter).

Comment: If you are sure your rect won't overlap (and thus you can split their drawings by color), then even drop fillRect and compose a single path per color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of iterations isn't huge, their time required is pretty much identical, but if you have a ton, it's better to avoid reassigning `c.fillStyle`, which looks to slow things down by around a factor of 5:

```js
const c = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

function oneLoop() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fillRect(5 + i * 2, 5, 5, 5);
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect(5 + i * 2, 15, 5, 5);
  }
}

function twoLoops() {
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    c.fillRect(5 + i * 2, 5, 5, 5);
  }

  c.fillStyle = "red";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    c.fillRect(5 + i * 2, 15, 5, 5);
  }
}
[oneLoop, twoLoops].forEach(fn => {
  const start = performance.now();
  fn();
  const end = performance.now();
  console.log(end - start);
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Changing the context properties is always a slow operation and should be avoided in loops as much as possible.